# Is it possible to decompress CompQueryDefs in Aspen InfoPlus.21/sqlplus?

Tags: sql, aspen

During storing of sql Skripts as CompQuery,Procedures or View-Records,
it throughs away any additional whitespace and comments. On top of that
it also encode most SQL-commands into a byte code to be interpreted by thy
according TSK_IQ/TSK_SQL_SERVER processes.

Is there a possibility to decompress these records back readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an sqlplus-Skript, which decodes CompQuery,Procedures and View-Records.
The Output of the skript is accurate, but needs some formatting 
(returns, whitespaces) and potentialls comments to get it in a good human
readable form.

```
-- Skript Decode_CompQueryDefs
-- initial version 11.12.2002
-- changes 09.08.2017 added Comments on english
-- 31.07.2018 code 9b changed to DESC, tested with ASC and DESC.

MACRO m_record = PROMPT('Which CompQuery,Stored Procedure or View?');;

-- codelist for the interpreted short cuts
DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE module.codelist
    (m_code INT,m_decode CHAR(40),m_return INT,m_mode INT);
LOCAL ix INT,l_LINE CHAR(512),l_bx CHAR(2),l_cx INT,
    l_result CHAR(255),iy INT,iz INT,l_stringmode INT;

SET LOG_ROWS = 0;
-- fill the code list
INSERT INTO module.codelist
    (m_code,m_decode,m_return)
  VALUES
    (CAST('c2' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'MACRO',3),
    (CAST('c1' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LOCAL',25),
    (CAST('af' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'FUNCTION',3),
    (CAST('b3' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'IF',3),
    (CAST('d0' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'RETURN',3),
    (CAST('ea' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'WHILE',3),
    (CAST('9d' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DO',4),
    (CAST('db' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' THEN',4),
    (CAST('95' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',1),
    (CAST('c7' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' OF',1),
    (CAST('ac' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' FOR',1),
    (CAST('ec' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' WITH',9),
    (CAST('9e' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'ELSE',6),
    (CAST('c6' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' OCCNUM',1),
    (CAST('a9' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'EXISTS',1),
    (CAST('d4' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'SELECT',9),
    (CAST('ae' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' FROM',9),
    (CAST('e9' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' WHERE',9),
    (CAST('86' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' AND',9),
    (CAST('9f' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'END',2),
    (CAST('d5' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' SET',9),
    (CAST('e4' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'UPDATE',3),
    (CAST('de' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TO',1),
    (CAST('88' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' AS',1),
    (CAST('89' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'BEGIN',6),
    (CAST('c9' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' OR',9),
    (CAST('c4' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' NOT',9),
    (CAST('e6' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' USING',1),
    (CAST('b0' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' GROUP',9),
    (CAST('8d' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' BY',1),
    (CAST('ca' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ORDER',9),
    (CAST('8a' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' BETWEEN',1),
    (CAST('b4' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' IN',1),
    (CAST('ba' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' IS',1),
    (CAST('c5' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' NULL',1),
    (CAST('be' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LIKE',1),
    (CAST('dd' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TIMESTAMP',1),
    (CAST('ad' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' FORMAT',1),
    (CAST('a1' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_CODE',9),
    (CAST('a0' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'ERROR',3),
    (CAST('a5' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_TEXT',9),
    (CAST('a6' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_TYPE',9),
    (CAST('a4' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_LINE',9),
    (CAST('a2' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_COLUMN',9),
    (CAST('a3' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ERROR_FILE',9),
    (CAST('ed' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'WRITE',3),
    (CAST('92' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'COMMIT',3),
    (CAST('9b' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DESC',1),
    (CAST('bc' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LEADING',1),
    (CAST('b6' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'INSERT',3),
    (CAST('b9' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' INTO',1),
    (CAST('8f' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'CASE',3),
    (CAST('e8' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'WHEN',3),
    (CAST('80' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ACTIVATION_FIELD',1),
    (CAST('82' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ACTIVATION_RECORD',1),
    (CAST('81' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ACTIVATION_PRIORITY',1),
    (CAST('e7' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' VALUES',25),
    (CAST('97' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'DECLARE',3),
    (CAST('da' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TEMPORARY',1),
    (CAST('d9' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TABLE',1),
    (CAST('c3' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' MODULE',1),
    (CAST('d7' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'START',3),
    (CAST('9a' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'DELETE',3),
    (CAST('98' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DEFAULT',1),
    (CAST('b2' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' HISTSEQNUM',1),
    (CAST('bf' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LINE',1),
    (CAST('c0' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LINENUM',1),
    (CAST('d8' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' SYSTEM',1),
    (CAST('df' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TRAILING',1),
    (CAST('85' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ALL_RECORDS',1),
    (CAST('ce' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' RECID',1),
    (CAST('eb' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' WIDTH',1),
    (CAST('87' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ANY',1),

    (CAST('8b' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' BIT',1),
    (CAST('8c' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' BREAK',1),
    (CAST('90' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' CENTER',1),
    (CAST('93' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' CORRESPONDING',1),
    (CAST('94' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' CREATE',1),
    (CAST('96' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DATE_FORMAT',1),
    (CAST('9c' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DIAGNOSTICS',1),
    (CAST('a8' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' EXECUTE',1),
    (CAST('aa' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' FALSE',1),
    (CAST('b8' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' INTERVALL',1),
    (CAST('bb' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' JOIN',1),
    (CAST('bd' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' LEVEL',1),
    (CAST('c8' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ON',1),
    (CAST('cb' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' PAGE',1),
    (CAST('cc' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' RAND',1),
    (CAST('d1' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' RIGHT',1),
    (CAST('d2' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ROLLBACK',1),
    (CAST('d3' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ROWID',1),
    (CAST('e0' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' TRUE',1),
    (CAST('d6' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' SKIP',1),
    (CAST('e2' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' UNION',1),
    (CAST('e3' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' UNKNOWN',1),
    (CAST('99' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' DEFINITION',1),
    (CAST('b1' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' HAVING',9),
    (CAST('ef' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'WAIT',3),
    (CAST('83' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'ACTTSK',3),
    (CAST('8e' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' CALCULATE',1),

    (CAST('09' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' ',0),

    (CAST('a7' AS INT USING 'Z5'),'EXCEPTION',6),
    (CAST('b7' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' INT',1),
    (CAST('cf' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' RECORD',1),
    (CAST('cd' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' REAL',1),
    (CAST('ab' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' FIELD',1),
    (CAST('91' AS INT USING 'Z5'),' CHAR',1)
    ;


    -- doing some preparations with codelist.
UPDATE module.codelist SET m_mode = 1;

FOR ix = 32 TO 126 DO
  INSERT INTO module.codelist
    (m_code,m_decode,m_return,m_mode)
    VALUES
    (ix,CHR(ix),0,0);
END;

  UPDATE module.codelist
    SET m_mode = 8
    WHERE m_code = 39;


UPDATE module.codelist
    SET m_return = BIT_OR(m_return,16)
    WHERE BIT_AND(m_return,5) <> 0;
UPDATE module.codelist
    SET m_return = BIT_OR(m_return,8)
    WHERE BIT_AND(m_return,2) <> 0;

iy = 0;
l_stringmode = 0;
WRITE '-- Record: &m_record';
FOR (SELECT NAME,ONUM,QUERY_LINE FROM 
     ( SELECT NAME,OCCNUM AS ONUM,QUERY_LINE FROM CompQueryDef WHERE NAME = '&m_record'
     UNION
      SELECT NAME,OCCNUM AS ONUM,QUERY_LINE FROM ProcedureDef WHERE NAME = '&m_record'
     UNION
      SELECT NAME,OCCNUM AS ONUM,QUERY_LINE FROM ViewDef WHERE NAME = '&m_record'
     )
    ORDER BY ONUM
    ) DO
  l_LINE = QUERY_LINE;
  ix = 1;l_cx = 1;
  l_bx = SUBSTRING(l_line FROM 1 FOR 2);
  WHILE l_bx <> '' DO
    ix = ix + 2;
    l_cx = CAST(l_bx AS INT USING 'Z5');
    IF l_cx = 39 THEN
    l_stringmode = BIT_XOR(l_stringmode,1);
    END;--IF
    CASE l_stringmode
    WHEN 1 THEN
    l_result = l_result || CHR(l_cx);
    WHEN 0 THEN
        iz = iy;
        iy = COALESCE( (SELECT m_return FROM module.codelist
            WHERE m_code = l_cx),0);
        CASE
        WHEN l_cx = 0 AND l_result <> '' THEN
        WRITE l_result;
        l_result = '';
        iy = 0; 
        WHEN l_cx = 0 AND l_result = '' THEN
        iy = 0; 
        WHEN BIT_AND(iy,2)=2 AND l_result <> '' THEN -- Return before
        WRITE l_result;
        l_result = COALESCE( (SELECT m_decode FROM module.codelist
            WHERE m_code = l_cx),'<<'||l_bx||'>>');
        WHEN (CHAR_LENGTH(l_result) > 80)
          AND BIT_AND(iy,8)=8 THEN-- Break is allowed before
        WRITE l_result;
        l_result = COALESCE( (SELECT m_decode FROM module.codelist
            WHERE m_code = l_cx),'<<'||l_bx||'>>');
        WHEN BIT_AND(iz,1)= 1 THEN -- blank towards predecessor
        l_result = l_result || ' ' ||
          COALESCE( (SELECT m_decode FROM module.codelist
            WHERE m_code = l_cx),'<<'||l_bx||'>>');
        ELSE
        l_result = l_result ||
          COALESCE( (SELECT m_decode FROM module.codelist
            WHERE m_code = l_cx),'<<'||l_bx||'>>');
        END;--IF
        CASE
        WHEN BIT_AND(iy,4)=4 THEN
        WRITE l_result;
        l_result = '';
        iy = BIT_XOR(iy,BIT_AND(iy,1));--supress blank
        WHEN BIT_AND(iy,16) =16
          AND CHAR_LENGTH(l_result) >80 THEN
        WRITE l_result;
        l_result = '';
        iy = BIT_XOR(iy,BIT_AND(iy,1));--supress blank
        END;--CASE
        IF l_cx = 32 THEN 
        iy = BIT_OR(iy,1);
        END;--IF
    END;--if l_stringmode = 0
    l_bx = SUBSTRING(l_line FROM ix FOR 2);
  END;--WHILE
END;--FOR
```

**EDITED 31-JUL-2018:** changed code 9b to DESC and tested ok.

Comment: The `9b` token in not ASC but DESC.

I have saved the following procedure: `PROCEDURE TEST SELECT NAME FROM IP_AnalogDef order by name desc; END`

Your (otherwise amazing) query returns `PROCEDURE TESTSELECT NAME FROM IP_AnalogDef ORDER  BY name ASC ; END`

Comment: Thanks @Maxime, I've corrected it above and tested it with ASC and DESC working fine.

Comment: Beautiful script, thank you! I often want to find where a table is being referenced or a procedure is called, and I can work this into a larger search system.